# Why is this 'if' statement looping?

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

Hey guys I'm writing part of a code for a project and I'm stuck on one thing. If this is something good coders figure out on their own at some point (as I'd like to become a good one, week five with c++; so far so good...) and its a trial, say the word and I'll screw, but I've been at debugging for about a half hour and don't understand why my 'if' statement is looping.

The input should look like this:

> p 11:34 12:45

Where p indicates if you're done (it'll be 's' if you want it to be out, represented here by 'end').

```
const int LIST_SPACE = 1000; // this is outside of the main function
string c;                    // and is 1000 because of a parameter set by the teacher
string end = "s";
string start = "p";
int temp_start_hour;
int temp_start_min;
int temp_end_hour;
int temp_end_min;

string colon = ":";
int begin_hours[LIST_SPACE];
int begin_min[LIST_SPACE];
int end_hours[LIST_SPACE];
int end_min[LIST_SPACE];
int i = 0;
do {
    cin >> c; //where c is a string

    if(c != start && c != end)
    {
        cout << "ERROR IN INPUT";
        return 1;
    }

    if(c != end)
    {
        cin >> temp_start_hour >> colon >> temp_start_min;
        cin >> temp_end_hour >> colon >> temp_end_min;
        begin_hours[i] = temp_start_hour;
        begin_min[i] = temp_start_min;
        end_hours[i] = temp_end_hour;
        end_min[i] = temp_end_min;
        cout << begin_hours[i]; //I did this to check if it was storing values
        i++;
    }
 }while(c != end); //ending the do-while loop
```

I'd really appreciate a nudge in the right direction with this guys. Or advice in general on a concept I'm missing. Thanks!

The output I keep getting, by the way is: (this is for the input 'p 11:34 12:34')

```
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
111111111111111111111Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: The project as a whole involves comparing a list of calls to see whether or not one plan is better than the other. The answer to your question is yes, so if you can't help I understand, but believe me when I say that input is barely scratching the surface of the meat of this project. Really I'm just conceptually confused with why this would happen.

Comment: What does `start` and `end` hold?

Comment: start and end are strings holding 'p' and 's' respectively.
c is a string holding one character from the input.

Comment: You are messing up on your stream operators for processing the time input.

Comment: How so? The way it should be working now is that it takes the input of , for example, `p 11:34 12:34` and checks to see if the first character is a 'p', 's', or neither (if it's a p continue, s end there, and if its anything else return with errors). That's why the cin is split between the 'c' and the rest.

Comment: what is `colon`?  Best guess, you're running off the end of your input and then all further reads from `cin` become noops, as you never check for eof

Comment: Post the **type** of EACH variable you're using in `std::cin`.

Comment: The p/c part works, but the hours/minutes/colons part isn't correct.

Comment: `string colon = ":"` it's just there to make sure I get the integers from the input.

Comment: @Nawaz how do you mean, I'm sorry to ask such an elementary question. It worked before in this format.

Comment: @JamesRoseman: What are the data types of the variables? Is this so difficult to understand? You don't know what a data type is?

Comment: @Nawaz sorry, I was in the middle of posting the declarations and initializations, I just didn't fully understand what you meant by `std::cin` I apologize. I do know what data types are, and just posted them, and really appreciate you helping me out.

Comment: @JamesRoseman: `std::cin` is same as what you mean by `cin` in your program. Since `cin` is an object defined in `std` namespace, so I wrote `std::cin` instead of just `cin`. What I wrote is called *qualified name* and what you've written is called *unqualified name*. Hope this makes things clear.

Comment: @Nawaz That clears things up a lot, and I'm sorry I forgot to mention it, but there should also be an `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;` above what's edited there. My apologies, it's about 2:30 where I am. Would using your way over mine fix the error I keep getting? I quite simply am really confused as to why it would loop at all without properly functioning.

Comment: @JamesRoseman: I just assumed that you've written those header at the top. Anyway, now let me look into the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that 'colon' gets all of ":34", then start_minutes gets the 12 that was supposed to be the next hour. But the real problem is that cin leaves cruft on the stream that is picked up by subsequent calls, so those calls skip asking you for more input and just take the left over characters. Use cin.ignore() after each call as a kludgy patch to make it work, but think alot harder about redesigning the whole thing with the safer functions.

Comment: Would this be solved by switching `string colon = ":"` to `char colon = ':'` ? Thank you, by the way, this means a lot to me. -- Actually, I'm just going to try it out myself, no need to be a baby haha.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you so much, I can't believe I didn't look close enough to see that :-( Learn from experiences right? I really appreciate your help, and everyone's for that matter.

Comment: By "make it work", I mean keep asking you for input so you have a chance to exit cleanly.  It still won't do what you think it should with regard to storing the time input in your variables, but you can debug that the old fashioned way.

Comment: Yeah I switched the data type from a string to a char, and it's working fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong :

```
cin >> temp_start_hour >> colon >> temp_start_min;
```

What it means : read an int, then read a string, and finally read another int. The value of the variable `colon` is not read at all.

You can try the following code to see how it behaves :

```
string sep = ":";
int a, b;

cin >> a >> sep >> b;

cout << a << endl;
cout << sep << endl;
cout << b << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the type of the variable `colon`. The fix is very simple: just change the type of `colon` from `string` to `char`:

```
//string colon = ":"; //commenting out the old code
char colon; //new code : no need to initialize it
```

Why `string colon` causes problem because when the type is `string` the `cin` reads all characters beginning from `':'` to a character until it encounters a *space*, when in fact, you intend to read **only a single** character called`':'`. For which, the correct data type is `char` (or you can choose `unsigned char` as well).

Comment: Thanks, I found the bug at around 3 and fixed it up. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score -1):

You are not incrementing the `c` variable

Comment: But the c variable takes input at the first line after the do, meaning that it should change when the loop occurs. My problem is that it won't let me enter more than one line at a time. As soon as I hit enter after that second set of numbers '12:34' is entered it just goes rather than waiting for 'c' to be equal to an 's'.